Formula to extract from cell, anything that comes before the first text and number string
In Excel, I am trying to find a formula to do the following
I have a list of addresses with postal codes that are either 3 or 6 characters:
Cell A1: 3 Red Street, Vancouver, BC, A1C 9C2, CAN

Cell A2: 25 Blue Street, Toronto, ON, B5R, CAN

Cell A3: 10 Yellow Street, Halifax, NS, K6L 8B4, CAN

I am trying to extract the following in another column:
Cell B1: 3 Red Street, Vancouver, BC

Cell B2: 25 Blue Street, Toronto, ON

Cell B3: 10 Yellow Street, Halifax, NS

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

=TEXTJOIN(",",,CHOOSECOL(TEXTSPLIT(A1,","),1,2,3))?

Or to handle all input, B1 = =MAP(A1:A3, LAMBDA(addr, TEXTJOIN(",", , CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(addr, ","), 1, 2, 3))))

In B1: =TEXTBEFORE(A1:A3,",",3). Or maybe for 'before comma, space, capital alpha, digit, capital alpha'
=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A3,REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A3,", [A-Z][0-9][A-Z]")).

=TEXTJOIN(",",,CHOOSECOL(TEXTSPLIT(A1,","),1,2,3)). This one I was getting a #NAME? error.
I was also going to put the formula into a VBA code to use across multiple workbooks. Column A will vary in the number of rows. I will test out the other formulas provided below. Thank you for your responses and help with this.

@leever: CHOOSECOL should be CHOOSECOLS.

If you are using Excel 365 -
=TEXTJOIN(",",,CHOOSECOLS(TEXTSPLIT(A1,","),1,2,3))

Earlier versions of Excel -
=LEFT(A1, FIND(",", A1, FIND(",", A1, FIND(",", A1) + 1) + 1) - 1)

You can also consider Flash Fill which is a very handy option as well.

Inspired by Michal's, adding an alternative for Excel 2016:

Select the range to match the number of rows in input
Enter as an array formula using Control + Shift + Enter
Assuming "¶" is not used in addresses

find the number of ,s, replace the penultimate one with "¶"
use that to get the left of postal code



=LEFT(
    A1:A3,
    FIND(
        "¶",
        SUBSTITUTE(
            A1:A3,
            ",",
            "¶",
            LEN(A1:A3) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A3, ",", "")) - 1
        )
    ) - 1
)



Here are few alternative ways using MS365 Excel Functions or using older legacy functions.


• Using MS365 Excel Functions : Formula used in cell B1
=ARRAYTOTEXT(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(A1,", "),,3))


Can spill the above using one of the followings as well:
=MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(α,ARRAYTOTEXT(TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(α,", "),,3))))

Or,
=MAP(A1:A5,LAMBDA(α,TEXTJOIN(", ",1,TAKE(TEXTSPLIT(α,", "),,3))))


• Using Older Excel Functions which works from Excel 2010+ onwards:
=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",REPT(" ",100),3),100))


Or,
=TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ",REPT(" ",100),3),COLUMN(A1)*100-99,100))



Hello if the addresses on column A have always exact number of commas like in this case 4 this is a short solution for your case in Excel 2021:
=LEFT(A2,SEARCH("|",SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","|",3))-1)

Hope it helps.
